# Не читаются GET без прямой ссылки на index.php

Tags: apache, .htaccess, php, сервер

Проблема такова. Есть папка demo. В ней .htaccess с таким содержимым

> Allow from all

Когда я захожу на http://mee/demo/index.php?thm=typess то с помощью PHP выводится содержимое GET, но если же я захожу на http://mee/demo/?thm=typess, то $_GET['thm'] является пустой строкой. В чем может быть дело? Движок CMS DLE. Может то что там особенный htaccess в корне?

В общем помогите плиз. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Во втором url не указан скрипт, которому передается get-запрос.

Comment: @Lucky Так index.php. Всегда работает, а в данном случае - нет

Comment: Тогда попробуйте без последнего слеша. Может повезет :)

Comment: @Lucky Да это все тут не причем. Это проблема с htaccess. Мне помогал кто то решить эту проблему, но я уже не помню как.

Answer (score 1):

Попробовать написать в .htaccess

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
```